# Google Analytics - Filter Regexp

Tags: google-analytics

Will this filter for Google Analytics do what I think it's going to:

/pages/(2377|2363|2365|2366|2324|2364|2751|2310).asp

I need only those particular pages.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will only show `/pages/2377.asp`, `/pages/2363.asp`, etc...